# Conflict when try to delete Mercurial tag

Tags: mercurial, .hgtags

I have stable tag in my Mercurial repository, and I was able to tag new stable releases of code, and everything worked perfect.

But we decided to have stable branch, which will contain only stable code, and I created this branch, but now I have problem to switch to Hg "stable" branch and not to Hg "stable" tag.

Therefore, because stable tags will not be used anymore, I thought to delete those tags using command:
hg tag --remove stable

But I got warning:

hg tag --remove stable
warning: tag stable conflicts with existing branch name
.hgtags

How can I resolve this weird problem? Is it reccomanded to manually edit .hgtags file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can manually edit the `.hgtags` file.  It's just another file in the repository.  If you screw it up you can just re-edit it and re-commit it.